# Aggregating pairwise ratings in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, dag

A finite set of individuals provide bounded non-binary pairwise ratings of other individuals (say, -10 to +10), forming a directed graph (cycles possible).

I'd like to determine aggregate ratings for each individual that considers all of that individual's inbound ratings and the aggregate ratings of the upstream individuals that provided them, and so on upstream and downstream.

For example, Alice rates Bob. If Alice's own aggregate rating is high, then Alice's rating of Bob (whether high or low) factors strongly into Bob's aggregate rating. If Alice's own aggregate rating is low, then Alice's rating of Bob does not affect Bob's aggregate rating much. And so on for Bob's ratings to others.

The iterative algorithm needs to stabilize at a bounded non-trivial result for any combination of the allowed ratings.

Elo requires undirected edges (whereas Alice may rate Bob but Bob may not rate Alice), zero-sum ratings (whereas Alice may rate Bob +10 at the same time as Bob rates Alice +10), and binary outcomes (though I feel like it could be tweaked for non-binary outcomes).

PageRank assumes every outbound edge from a given vertex has equal weight. Can this be modified for variable edge weights and still be kept stable (e.g. if everyone gives +10 to everyone else)?

Any pointers on what the right algo might be here?

Comment: What properties do you want the result to have?  "considers" is pretty open-ended.  You might also be interested in Advogato and trust metrics for Sybil defense.  Perhaps that would help identify what your specific requirements are?

Comment: There is an entire area dedicated to such questions and topics: social choice theory, and more particularly, judgment aggregation.

Comment: Pagerank variants for weighted graphs are well studied. The probability for the walker to choose a given neighbor is then proportional to the weight of the corresponding link.

Comment: If you want to allow positive and negative scores, then what you have is a (weighted) **signed** graph, which raises many challenges. There are some works on such graph, but not enough.